# Update stageVariables from Custom Authorizer $Context variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

This question may look similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775512/how-to-pass-data-to-backend-http-proxy-from-aws-custom-authorizer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222052/aws-api-gateway-custom-authorizer-with-proxy-setup-add-custom-headers-to-reque).

But my question is a little different:

I have an API Gateway that uses a Custom Authorizer and has multiple stages, most of the resources that have methods (GET / POST) have integration with a normal HTTP endpoint, meaning they just get "passthrough" to the endpoint in question (does not use HTTP Proxy integration).

Here is an example:
[image]

These endpoints all point to stageVariables.

However, for a particular reason I need to update this stageVariable before calling it. My thinking is by setting and getting the `$context.authorizer.variableName` from the `$context` of the Custom Auth.

My problem is, how would I then update this value if I'm not using a Lambda.

It seems you can use Body Mapping Templates somehow (see [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) and [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference)) but I'm not sure how to use them to update the stageVariable?

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not supported. You can set values in the context, but not change the stage variables http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html.

Comment: @AbhignaNagaraja okay, but then how would you use the context variables within the Integration request? Something to note, i'm using .NET Core C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else ever runs into this issue.

After 3 days of assistance from the AWS team, it seems there are 2 issues here;

1 - Confirmed that changing of stageVariables (at all) is not currently possible.

2 - There is a limitation with the `$context` and `$authorizer` variables within the body. As a side note: there has been a new service request been created and being worked on by the AWS team for this.

To explain:

Currently, in node.js you have access to the entire payload of data being passed through to the Lambda function (within the `event` parameter), which includes all custom variables. This is not the same for the `C#` equivalent - which uses the [APIGatewayProxyRequest](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs) request object within a Lambda function. So although you have access to the entire payload (including all the custom variables) within node, within C#, you only have access to the [APIGatewayProxyRequest](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs) object. Properties of which can be found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs):

Or in short:

```
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Headers { get; set; }
    public string HttpMethod { get; set; }
    public bool IsBase64Encoded { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> PathParameters { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> QueryStringParameters { get; set; }
    public ProxyRequestContext RequestContext { get; set; }
    public string Resource { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> StageVariables { get; set; }
```

Hence, not allowing access to custom or "unknown" object(s).

Long story short, as of right now: you cannot edit `stageVariables` through code and if you wish you work with custom variables of any sort within the payload being sent through, you would either need to code it through node(`event`) / python, or possibly overwrite an existing property within the [APIGatewayProxyRequest](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/APIGatewayProxyRequest.cs) object.

**UPDATE(to handle #2):**

There is a work around to accessing the entire payload of the data coming in:

> A work around till then is have your Lambda function take in a System.IO.Stream instead of APIGatewayProxyRequest. Then you have access to the original JSON which you can parse yourself. You can grab the information you need from that JSON and then deserialize JSON to APIGatewayProxyRequest as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can set values in the context, but not change the stage variables

```
var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
    var authResponse = {};
    //...
    // Can optionally return a context object of your choosing.
    authResponse.context = {};
    authResponse.context.stringKey = "stringval";
    authResponse.context.numberKey = 123;
    authResponse.context.booleanKey = true;
    return authResponse;
}
```

The context will be available in

> $context.authorizer.stringKey ...

which can be added to the integration request mapping template to pass to your backend.

Comment: As stated in my previous comment on the question, this work is being done in C# .NET Core, hence, this code would not help.

Comment: As long as you return a object with the same keys, it'll work. The code is an example in node js.

Comment: The problem here is that this is node code, we are still battling (with AWS help) to get the equivalent in .NET core C#. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990385/aws-lambda-c-sharp-accessing-custom-context

Comment: PS - I've upvoted this as, although it doesn't answer the question it is still right (for node) and could still be useful to someone.